# Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCardView not found

Tags: android, material-components

https://material.io/develop/android/theming/shape/

The site describes how to customize a MaterialCardView, but when I choose Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCardView as my parent in my style file it can't be found.

I tried to do it with Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView, but it got me a grey background for my card. I could fix the grey background with app:cardForegroundColor which works fine for most cases, but when I use the MaterialCardView in some special cases like as a BottomSheet, the build-in animations for the automatic corner transition makes the grey background again visible.
I'm anyway not happy with app:cardForegroundColor because I think it shouldn't be used when possible.

[image]

In the end I could fix all of the problems by choosing the parent as Theme.MaterialComponents,
but I would still like to know what I did wrong or how it should actually be done.

I used androidx and com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Style: must have as parent a MaterialComponents theme if you are using *AndroidX*

```
 <style name="CardActivityTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorAccentX</item>
</style>
```

To create a beatiful outlined material card in Google style, create it in your activity XML layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/card0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFF"
            app:strokeWidth="1dp"
            app:strokeColor="DADCE0"
            app:cardElevation="0dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

I have made some attributes hardcoded to give you directly the colors.

Result:

[image: card]

If you prefer the normal elevated card, and not the outlined use this:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/card0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFF"
            app:cardElevation="1dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Notice that i have deleted from the previous one the attributes **app:strokeWidth** and **app:strokeColor**.

Finally, if you want to create an animation like in the GIF you have posted, I strongly recommend to use [Motion Layout.](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I have already fixed it with an other aproach, but how would I get it running with Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCardView .. because that's the way the documentation somehow prefers it